# What type of file is ~$file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I had opened *msoffice* file that I had previously saved on my desktop, I saw another kind of file named *~$doc*. What type of file is this ?

[image: screenshot with both files - the original and the ghostly twin]

I have marked both the files.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's a temporary file that disappears when you close Word.

[Description of how (and why) Word creates temporary files (in the same directory)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-how-word-creates-temporary-files-66b112fb-d2c0-8f40-a0be-70a367cc4c85)

This particular file is actually an Owner File.

From that KB article:

> Owner File (Same Directory as Source File):
>
> When a previously saved
> file is opened for editing, for printing, or for review, Word creates
> a temporary file that has a .doc file name extension. This file name
> extension begins with a tilde (~) that is followed by a dollar sign
> ($) that is followed by the remainder of the original file name. This
> temporary file holds the logon name of person who opens the file. This
> temporary file is called the "owner file."
>
> When you try to open a file that is available on a network and that is
> already opened by someone else, this file supplies the user name for
> the following error message: This file is already opened by user name.
> Would you like to make a copy of this file for your use?

Answer (score 16):

Actually, **it is a temporary "lock"** for the file that you are writting.

If someone else try to edit the same file(if you are editing a file on a network share for example), this lock will disallow simultaneous editions. [Here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1075940) is a quick reference.

Comment: I had thought the similar (even that it was an 'original copy' incase you closed and didn't want to save changes) until i read above :)

Comment: HaydnWVN, an owner file is actually a lock file, so what Diogo said is not incorrect.