# ~$ prefixed hidden file doesn't show in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

**OS: Windows 8.1**

While programming I needed to create a hidden file. Like MS Word does when you open a document you see a `~$documentname.docx` file that is hidden. So I created a file `~$anything.extension` and made it hidden. While viewing the directory in Windows Explorer I was able to see the file. Once I hit F5, the file disappeared. First I thought my code was doing something weird and deleting it, but my code would find the file using `File.Exist`. I can see the file in command prompt running `dir /a` and I can open it and see the contents of the file. But if I try `del "~$name.extension"` it can't find the file.

I've also noticed you can replicate the same behavior by just opening a MS Word document and you will see the `~$document.docx` hidden file. Then if you F5 in the directory it will disappear.

My question is: Why does giving the prefix of ~$ and hidden attribute make the file disappear even though you have hidden items showing in the settings? Is this suppose to be expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried and got the same results. I was able to get the file to show up by unchecking `Hide protected operating system files`. It looks like when these types of files are hidden, they are automatically set as operating system files. Therefore you need to show/unhide those as well.

If you wish to learn more about the file type: [What type of file is ~$file?](https://superuser.com/questions/405257/what-type-of-file-is-file)